# How to make a formula to link two sequences without any positioning numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two sequences:

sequence $n$: $4, 7, 10, 13$

sequence $p: 10, 16, 22, 28$

I wish to find a link between them i.e. $p=??$

However, I cannot use positioning numbers, so you can't say that $4$ is the first term, $7$ is the second term, etc.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Am I totally confusing myself...?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Something like $p=2n+2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's right and obvious, but what are the steps to find the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observing, guessing and then verifying, we see that the sequences are related by $p=2n+2$.

Comment: Yes, it's simple, but what are the actual steps to find the formula?

Comment: I observe, guess and verify that you **are** right!

Comment: Why not include that in your answer and I'll choose it as the right answer? ;)